# Maple: Comparing an index variable to an integer in the context of product

Tags: maple

I'm running into a strange problem. I want to implement a product in Maple with skipping some factors. For example (a very simplified one):

$$\prod_{\stackrel{k=1}{k \not= 3}}^{5} (x-k) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-5).$$

In Maple I wrote

`product(ifelse(k <> 3, x - k, 1), k = 1 .. 5)`

But I get

`(x - 1)*(x - 2)*(x - 3)*(x - 4)*(x - 5)`.

In other words, the `ifthen` seems to evaluate to true all the time.

I tested a little further and got those results:

```
product(i = 1, i = 1 .. 1);
                             1 = 1

product(evalb(i = 1), i = 1 .. 1);
                             false
```

So even when I force the evaluation with `evalb` I never get a true. The type of the index variable `k` is an ordinary symbol and outside of the `product`-context, comparing a symbol does work:

```
k := 1;
                             k := 1

k = 1;
                             1 = 1

evalb(k = 1);
                              true
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `product` command follows Maple's usual model of evaluation, in which the arguments passed to procedure calls are evaluated up front.

In other words, that call to `ifelse` gets evaluated before `product` sees it. What the `product` command receives is this result:

```
ifelse(k <> 3, x - k, 1);

             x - k
```

You can see this via `trace`.

```
trace(product):
product(ifelse(k <> 3, x - k, 1), k = 1 .. 5);
  {--> enter product, args = x-k, k = 1 .. 5
  ....
```

In contrast, the `mul` command has so-called [special evaluation rules](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=spec_eval_rules), in which its first argument is not evaluated until the index name `k` actually attains its numeric values.

```
mul(ifelse(k <> 3, x - k, 1), k = 1 .. 5);

      (x - 1) (x - 2) (x - 4) (x - 5)
```

This is a common mistake. (It's seen more often with `sum` versus `add`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your thorough explanation! In all honesty, I wasn't aware of Maple's evaluation scheme but of course it explains everything!

Comment: You could also forcibly delay the evaluation of that first argument by placing single right-ticks (aka uneval quotes) around the word ifelse, while using `product` in your example. But that's not such a robust approach in general, and can get messy with nested products. Also, you are computing an exact result with multiplication of finitely many terms (and the end-points of the index are numeric). So this is not a "symbolic product", with an answer of a closed formula that might attain for some example for k=1..N with N unassigned. So `mul` really is the appropriate choice, not `product`.